# nested gridview row values

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, boundfield

I have this code:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="something">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Style="display: none" >
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeader="False">
                            <Columns>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="NAME"></asp:BoundField>
                              other  asp-BoundFields...
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
             asp-BoundFields...
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

CS: In function void Test() I want to get values from each row of gridview2. I tried with findcontrol method, but I think it is not possible to find BoundField. How can I do that?

Comment: can I see what you wrote in void test()?

Comment: Thanks for interest in my question, found out solution (check answer below).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found soultion on similar forum.

```
    GridView Gridview2 = (GridView)GridView1.Rows[1].FindControl("GridView2");
```